# Setting up users' home directories before they use mintty for the first tme

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to set up some Cygwin users on a Windows 2008 Server (that I have Administrator privileges on)  but I'm struggling to get their home directories set up.

Usually, if a user runs mintty as a login shell when their home directory doesn't exist (e.g. the first time they use "Cygwin Terminal"), the home directory gets created and copies of the the skeleton `.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc., from `/etc/skel` are added to it.

The problem I have is that I want to add some setup to the `.bashrc` for these users *without* changing the skeleton version (these settings won't necessarily be applicable for all future users).

I've tried creating the directory and copying the files over manually, but I can't then change the user/group ownership to the intended users - I get a "Permission denied" error from chown.

So, questions:

1. Why can't I (or how can I) get chown to assign ownership of a directory/file that I own to another user/group?
2. Is there actually a better way of creating a user's home directory and copying the skeleton files so I can modify them? (I'd like to avoid having to rely on the users doing something themselves to make the changes after they've logged in for the first time)

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to question 1:** Because I wasn't running the Cygwin shell as an adminstrator (i.e. right-click the Cygwin Terminal in the Start Menu and select "Run As Administrator", then the chown/chgrp both work as expected)

**Answer of sorts to question 2:** there is no magic involved in setting up the user's home directory for the first time: it's done by the default profile that bash executes if it can't find the user's home directory.